# ldd showing absolute path only

Tags: linux, elf

Under what circumstances does the output of `ldd` have only the absolute path?

In the below eg, `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so` and `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ file test
test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x28fd43cd2e96e8beb20de68e18d7dacbcc8af48d, not stripped
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ldd ./test
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0xb6f7e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e42000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f8c000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the absolute path is written inside the binary. Try `readelf -d test` and look at the NEEDED entries.

The `ld-linux` file is the dynamic interpreter and is always an absolute path.

**EDIT**: to see the dynamic interpreter info you need to dump the program headers (`readelf -l`). And I guess `libcofi_rpi.so` may be loaded by the interpreter and not your program.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that does not seem to list it either. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f706bf36a511122b0d13

Comment: @blahfish: see edit